# Browser based Ethereum app vs Wallet app

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, browsers

What are the pros and cons of having an Ethereum DApp running on a browser compared to the one in which each user is given a wallet?

This is question is for a DApp that would transfer files from user to user.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the one where each user is given a wallet?" I think, but am not sure, that you're asking to compare making a DApp that lives within Parity or Mist, versus something on the normal internet that just uses Metamask to interact with the blockchain. Is this a correct interpretation of what you're asking?

Comment: I am developing an application using blockchain. So I wanted to know if a desktop application based login is better or one in which there is a website and the login takes place through that/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean running "on a browser" the "light wallet", then

**pros:**

- user don't need to have anything on his computer (he should know only password and userId). So, it is lightweight
- user can access his account from any device (which has browser).

**cons:**

- user should TRUST the server, which manage his (and other users) accounts. So, it is not very good from security perspective.

> This is question is for a DApp that would transfer files from user to
>   user.

Be carefull - it is very doubtful idea to use blockchain for filesharing. Many are trying to do this, but in many cases the necessity of blockchain for that purpose is absent. So, think twice.